# different permissions for same amazon s3fs bucket mounted on 2 different instances?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, bucket, s3fs

I am mounting the same amazon bucket on 2 different Ubuntu server instances but ubuntu user can only write on the first one not the second. On the second one it has reading rights but not writing.

I am using this command to mount them:

```
 s3fs -o allow_other -o use_cache=/var/www/tempS3Cache/ mys3bucketname ./media/
```

-Ubuntu user belongs to same groups

-Ubuntu user is the owner of the mounted folders

-Ubuntu user the one mounting running s3fs command

-/etc/passwd-s3fs and /home/ubuntu/.passwd-s3fs have the same permissions on both servers

-on the first one I am using s3fs-1.62.tar.gz and on the second one s3fs-1.63.tar.gz to compile s3fs, could this be the problem?

Comment: You didn't mention whether /etc/passwd-s3fs and ~/.passwd-s3ds have identical contents on both servers, or what you really mean by "rights" -- do the unix permissions (e.g. '-rwxr-xr-x') look correct but an error occurs when you try to write?  What's the error?

Comment: Yep, both passwd files has identical contents on both servers. Permissions are set to 774 on both. I test with 777 on the second and now I can create subdirs but when trying to create files I get a badfile descriptor error, but the file get created. I am checking the fuse version on both machines now

Answer (score 0):

ok, so after some investigation I found out this is because a s3fs bug on version 1.63 https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/s3fs-devel/uksnbrBj6KM

using version 1.61 or 1.62 solve the problem but then you get bad file description if using cache
 https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/issues/detail?id=285&q=bad%20file